# How are the passband filters in SDRs able to select such a wide range of frequencies?

Tags: rf, integrated-circuit, communication, wireless

I was wondering how do SDRs adjust their passband for a such a wide range of frequencies?

The normal RF chain is, passband RF filter -> Mixer -> IF or baseband

Some SDRs can select their passband from being centered at 100khz to being centered at 3Ghz(with their IF or baseband range 20Mhz).

Does the SDR consist of hundreds of selectable RF bandpass filters or has someone come up with an adjustable one?

Comment: This occurs in the digital realm, after the IF stage. The Q and /Q outputs are processed by a fast DSP engine. Add digital controlled tuning to that and software determines all parameters.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question, to even get to the IF stage requires a bandpass filter.

Comment: Yes, multiple filters would be needed. Ceramic was in the past (am/fm radio), now SAW crystal filters are used. At the expensive end would be MEM's type crystals.

Comment: Except for such a wide range, you would need thousands in the IC. I don't think crystal filters are being used in the RTL SDR but I could be wrong.

Comment: Crystal filters have a very tight bandwidth. Ceramics have a wide bandwidth. Both of these have variations in bandwidth based on materials used. Varactors can also be used-adjustable capacitors.

Comment: Broadband front ends and mixers are certainly possible, and considerably predate SDRs. They usually have a high (and fixed) first (or only) IF and the main frequency selection is done by tuning/programming the LO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think many SDRs either have no filter or have a very wide filter at RF. Really, the main filtering required is at IF. And that can be a wide, fixed filter, followed up by narrower filters implemented with DSP. There is usually also some band switching to enable receiving inputs near our on the wrong side of the IF.

Consider the USRP-2954 SDR (block diagram from http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/373380G-01/usrphelp/2954_block_diagram/):

[image: USRP 2954 block diagram]

The frequency range is 10 MHz to 6 GHz.  For 500 MHz to 6 GHz, a single conversion is used to translate to baseband.  No tunable filters are required here, only fixed 80 MHz low pass filters between the mixer and the ADC.  A fixed 500 MHz or so high pass filter to remove anything in the vicinity of the baseband might be a good idea to avoid aliasing, not sure why it's not there.  For 10 MHz to 500 MHz, two conversions are used: one to convert up to 2.44 GHz, then one to bring that back down to baseband.  Again, this requires only a few fixed filters.

The HackRF One is similar (block diagram from http://www.dolstra.nl/Ham-radio/SDR_Tranceivers/HackRF%20One%20SDR/HackRF%20One%20SDR.htm):

[image: HackRF One block diagram]

In this case, there are two image reject filters (one fixed high pass, one fixed low pass).  Signals can be routed through one of those filters and a frequency converter or bypass the front end frequency conversion entirely.  None of this requires tunable filters.  The IF in this case is 2.3-2.7 GHz, converted to/from baseband with a MAX2837.

Also, if you really need an adjustable RF bandpass filter, they do exist, they just aren't cheap.  And they have been around for quite a few years.  YIG tuned filters can have a decently narrow bandwidth and can be tuned over several GHz.  They are relatively common in RF test equipment that works at relatively high frequencies (10 GHz+)

Comment: Interesting, so you're saying that using a mixer and a VCO, we can shift the frequency into the correct IF range for a fixed BPF over a wide range of freq. This makes sense.

Comment: Exactly. Much easier to tune an oscillator than a filter. Well, unless it's a DSP filter.

Answer (score 3):

> The normal RF chain is, passband RF filter -> Mixer -> IF or baseband

Yes, but it doesn't have to be.

A **spectrum analyser** front end works like this

Lowpass RF filter -> upmixer -> high first IF -> downmixer -> low 2nd IF -> further stages

For instance, the classic HP8566 starts off with a DC-2.5GHz LPF, and a variable 3GHz-5.5GHz LO to mix it up to a first IF at 3GHz, then mixed with a fixed 3.3GHz LO to bring it down to a 300MHz IF, before being further processed (approximate frequencies). This signal chain guarantees that if you see an output signal, you know there's an input signal, and you know at what frequency. But it's expensive.

Of course, all these filters *are not required* to make the system work at the wanted frequency. What the filters do is prevent signals at unwanted frequencies appearing in the output. If you are working with a good signal to noise ratio, for instance wire-connected to a transmitter, or receiving signals from a highly tuned antenna, then you do away with the need for filters at all, as long as you remain alert to the possibility that there might be false signals in the output.

In this case, you can use a **modulation meter** front end, which is

Lowpass RF filter -> harmonic sampling mixer -> low first IF

With a modulation meter configuration, if you see an output signal, you know there's at least one input signal, but you have to work out what its frequency is by trial and error, and if there's more than one input signal, you may be able to disentangle them, or you may not.